# Java: Method always returns same result

Tags: java, loops, methods, distance

I'm supposed to write a program for my programming class in High School. The program asks the user to input a time in seconds, and calculates the falling distance using the common formula d = 1/2 * g * t ^ 2. D is the distance (result), g equals 9.8 and t is the time the user entered. We are supposed to call the method 10 times for some reason. Here's my problem: The method always returns the same result (4.9 in the first iteration), no matter what the user's input for time was. What am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class fallingDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String input;
        double time;

        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the time in seconds: ");
        time = Double.parseDouble(input);
        System.out.println(time);
        for(int x=1; x<=10; x++){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The falling distance is: " + calculate(x) + "m.");
        }

    }

    public static double calculate(double time){
        double g = 9.8, a=0.5;
        double distance = (a*g) * (Math.pow(time, 2.0));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, distance);
        return (distance);
    }
}
```

Comment: You ask for time but you don't pass it to the calculate method.   You don't do anything with it except print it.  You do pass in the x value from the loop, so it's always 1-10 seconds.

Comment: Since this is for a programming class, I hope you do not mind that you comment on your code. You should change your for loop to `for(int x=0; x<10; x++)`. Your loop is not wrong, but it is more common for your iterator to start at 0.

Answer (score 5):

You are passing in `x` to the calculate method. Try passing in `time` instead.

Comment: Thank you. That works but now the program gives me the same result every time the loop iterates. How can I fix that?

Comment: What is the difference supposed to be in each iteration?

Comment: Are you maybe supposed to change the row `for(int x=1; x<=10; x++){` to `for(int x=0; x<10; x++){` and then change `calculate(time)` to `calculate(time + x)`? 
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I just got into class and tried it. Works perfectly for me.

Comment: @HenrikDierker If this is the answer you were looking for then please accept the answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you say return (distance)? I think you have to remove the brackets. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, didn't change anything though.

Comment: @Henrik Dierker, Try calculate() before you assign it in JOptionPane like, for(.......){double out = calculate(time); JOptionPane.......("...." + out + "m");}